# Angular CharJS option tooltip label did not work

Tags: chart.js, primeng

I have a component code like below

```
 changeData() {
        const changedData = this.getData();
        this.chartData = Object.assign({}, changedData);
        this.lineTooltips = this.getLineTooltips();
        this.chartOptions = {
            tooltips: {
                enabled: true,
                callbacks: {
                    label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                        return (data.tooltips[tooltipItem.index]).split('#');
                    },
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and also HTML file

```
<div class="chartStyle">
                <p-chart type="line" [data]="chartData" responsive="true" [options]="chartOptions" (onDataSelect)="selectData($event)"></p-chart>
```

The chart can load the line and data, but I hover to each item on the chart, the callback function did not work to load tooltip.

Answer (score 0):

If you log data.tooltips you will see its undefined, and since you try to read things from it it will throw an error and not draw anything.

Looking at the documentation I think you have to replace data.tooltips with data.datasets. (https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html#label-callback)

The best thing you can do is just log both  tooltipItem and data and go through the objects to see how you can combine them to get to the point you need and then insert that in your callback.

Comment: it still did not work, I changed  return "demo"; on callback function

Comment: Can you please provide a working example then to see where it might go wrong

Comment: https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/chart/line...I try to do based on this article with [options]="chartOptions", but did not work :(